# Easier way to calculate the derivative of $\ln(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}})$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

For the function $f$ given by
$$
\large \mathbb{R^+} \to \mathbb{R} \quad x \mapsto \ln \left (\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}} \right)
$$
I had to find $f'$ and $f''$.

Below, I have calculated them.
**But, isn't there a better and more convenient way to do this?**

---

My method:

$$
{f'(x)}=\left [\ln \left (\frac{x}{(x^2+1)^\frac{1}{2}} \right) \right ]'=\left (\frac{(x^2+1)^\frac{1}{2}}{x} \right)\left (\frac{x}{(x^2+1)^\frac{1}{2}} \right)'=\left (\frac{(x^2+1)^\frac{1}{2}}{x} \right) \left (\frac{(x^2+1)^\frac{1}{2}-x[(x^2+1)^\frac{1}{2}]'}{[(x^2+1)^\frac{1}{2}]^2} \right)=\left (\frac{(x^2+1)^\frac{1}{2}}{x} \right) \left (\frac{(x^2+1)^\frac{1}{2}-x[\frac{1}{2}(x^2+1)^{-\frac{1}{2}}(x^2+1)']}{\left | x^2+1 \right |} \right)=\left (\frac{(x^2+1)^\frac{1}{2}}{x} \right) \left (\frac{(x^2+1)^\frac{1}{2}-x[\frac{1}{2}(x^2+1)^{-\frac{1}{2}}(2x)]}{x^2+1} \right)=\left (\frac{(x^2+1)^\frac{1}{2}}{x} \right) \left (\frac{(x^2+1)^\frac{1}{2}-x^2(x^+1)^{-\frac{1}{2}}}{x^2+1} \right)=\frac{(x^2+1)^{(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2})}-x^2(x^2+1)^{\frac{1}{2}+-\frac{1}{2}{}}}{x(x^2+1)}=-\frac{x^2}{x}=-x
$$

and

$$
f''(x)=(-x)'=-1\
$$

This took me much more than 1.5 hours just to type into LaTex :'(

Comment: Your final step seems wrong. The answer seems to be $\frac{1}{x(x^2+1)}$.

Comment: As an aside, you could probably make this formula much easier in LaTeX if you copy your steps from previous lines and just chnage what you have to, as well as practice your typing of special characters. When I started using LaTeX, I was also abysmally slow, but now, if I have my formulas already worked out on paper, I can put them up in LaTeX pretty quickly. It's about practice, knowing the commands, and training your fingers to find those special characters like the exponent carat and the squiggly braces.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take advantage of logarithm properties.
$$\ln\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2 + 1}}\right) = \ln(x) - \frac12\ln(x^2 + 1)$$
Then the derivative is easy:
$$f'(x) = \frac1x - \frac{x}{x^2 + 1}$$

Answer (score 8):

#### Hint

$$\ln(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}})=\ln x-\frac{1}{2}\ln(x^2+1)$$

Answer (score 3):

The expression $$\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2 + 1}}$$
is the sine of the angle adjacent to $1$, in a right triangle with legs of $1$ and $x$ and hypotenuse $\sqrt{x^2 + 1}$.
Therefore, it is equal to
$$
\sin \arctan x
$$
and we have
$$
\bbox[5px,border:2px solid blue]{f(x) =  \ln (\sin (\arctan x)).}
$$
Computing $f'(x)$ for this is just chain rule twice:
$$
f'(x) = \frac{1}{\sin \arctan x} \cdot \cos \arctan x \cdot \frac{1}{1 + x^2}.
$$
Now referring to the original triangle, $\sin \arctan x = \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2 + 1}}$ and $\cos \arctan x = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2 + 1}}$, so
$$
f'(x) = \frac{\sqrt{x^2 + 1}}{x}
\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2 + 1}}
\cdot \frac{1}{x^2 + 1}
= \frac{1}{x(x^2 + 1)}.
$$

Note your answer was incorrect.

Comment: +1 for a geometric argument, as well as an unusual approach to these kinds of computations.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:
\begin{align}
f(x) = \log|x| - \frac{1}{2}\log|x^2+1|.
\end{align}

Comment: You seem to have introduced the absolute value from nowhere. It is not necessary in either expression.

Comment: It's a habit of mine.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)=\log\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}\right)$ and 
$$ g(t)=f(\sinh t) = \log\tanh t = \log\sinh t-\log\cosh t. $$
We have
$$ \frac{d}{dt}g(t) = \frac{\cosh t}{\sinh t}-\frac{\sinh t}{\cosh t} = \frac{1}{\sinh(t)\cosh(t)}$$
but the LHS also equals $\cosh(t)\,f'(\sinh t)$, hence
$$ f'(\sinh t) = \frac{1}{\sinh(t)\cosh^2(t)} $$
and
$$ f'(x) = \color{red}{\frac{1}{x(1+x^2)}}.$$
We may freely assume $x>0$ since otherwise $f(x)$ makes no sense (and $f'(x)$ as well).

Answer (score 0):

By implicit differentiation:

Let
$$
y(x) = \log\left[\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2 + 1}}\right].
$$
Then
$$
(x^2 + 1)e^{2 y(x)} = x^2.
$$
Differentiating both sides,
$$
(x^2 + 1)e^{2y(x)}y'(x) + x e^{2y(x)} = x.
$$
Solving for $y'(x)$,
$$
y'(x) = \frac{x(e^{-2y(x)}-1)}{(x^2 + 1)} = \frac{1}{x(x^2+1)}.
$$